# How to make bash completion work for git alias?

Tags: bash, git, bash-completion

I create git alias `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
xxx = !bash -c 'git rebase ...'
```

But when I type `git xxx`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> in shell I get list of files in current directory instead of list of branches available as it for `git rebase`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

**Is there a way to make bash auto completion for `git xxx`?** like for usual alias:

```
__git_complete grb _git_rebase
```

Comment: What dou you expect from completion? List of files to rebase, branches, list of commits?

Comment: @bimlas: list of branches available as it for `git rebase`TAB+TAB

Comment: Are you sure you need `bash` for this at all? `[alias] xxx = rebase ...`

Comment: @chepner: that is for example. Actually there is a multiline script

Comment: What version of 'git-completion.bash' are you using? This should work correctly since Git v1.8.

Comment: @FelipeC: I do not know. that file does not have info about version

Comment: @EugenKonkov Where did you get it from?

Comment: @FelipeC: Do not remember already.

Comment: Get the latest one. It should just work: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/plain/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

~/.bashrc

```
_git_xxx ()
{
  _git_rebase
}
```

~/.gitconfig

```
[alias]
xxx = !bash -c 'git rebase ...'
```

---

For example `_git_rebase` looks like this (found in *git-completion.bash* - the path of this file depends on your system, use `locate`, `find`, whatever to find it):

```
_git_rebase ()
{
        __git_find_repo_path
        if [ -f "$__git_repo_path"/rebase-merge/interactive ]; then
                __gitcomp "--continue --skip --abort --quit --edit-todo"
                return
        elif [ -d "$__git_repo_path"/rebase-apply ] || \
            [ -d "$__git_repo_path"/rebase-merge ]; then
                __gitcomp "--continue --skip --abort --quit"
                return
        fi
        __git_complete_strategy && return
        case "$cur" in
        --whitespace=*)
                __gitcomp "$__git_whitespacelist" "" "${cur##--whitespace=}"
                return
                ;;
        --*)
                __gitcomp "
                        --onto --merge --strategy --interactive
                        --preserve-merges --stat --no-stat
                        --committer-date-is-author-date --ignore-date
                        --ignore-whitespace --whitespace=
                        --autosquash --no-autosquash
                        --fork-point --no-fork-point
                        --autostash --no-autostash
                        --verify --no-verify
                        --keep-empty --root --force-rebase --no-ff
                        --exec
                        "

                return
        esac
        __git_complete_refs
}
```

Copy this function, rename to `_git_whatever` for example, change it as you like and put it in to your `~/.bashrc` then use `__git_complete gwhat _git_whatever` to make an alias from it.

Completion will work out of the box on `git whatever<TAB><TAB>` withouth the `__git_complete ...` step.

To prevent code duplication, you can bind your alias completion to an existing one:

```
_git_xxx ()
{
  _git_rebase
}
```

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, sorry for edits, but I found the real solution.

Comment: `_git_xxx` really works! Is it worth to put that solution in top of answer? so others will find that easy

Comment: How to do the same with git aliases like this: `merge-pr`, it seems hardly work with dashes